# Find if an item already exists in STL queue

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, find, queue

I am using an STL queue to implement a BFS (breadth first search) on a graph. I need to push a node in the queue if that node already doesn't exist in the queue. However, STL queue does [not allow iteration through its elements](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/queue.html#2) and hence I cannot use the STL find function.

I could use a flag for each node to mark them when they are visited and push them only when the flag is false, however, I need to run BFS multiple times and after each time I will have to reset all the flags, so I ended up using a counter instead of a flag, but I still would like to know if there is a standard way of finding an item in a queue.

Comment: What you want is a separate data store to store color of the nodes in your graph. If each node has a unique identifier that can be used as key, then you can use `std::map` to store color (white, gray, black) of the nodes. This will be `O(log(n)` as `std::map` is implemented as RB tree in most of the implementations.

Comment: @Vikas: I believe this is equivalent to assigning a counter to each node.

Comment: each node in BFS goes through three states, not-visited, visited-but-not-finished, finished. I don't really know what you meant by assigning counters to each node. But if you can achieve maintaining tri-state of a node, you can use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're implementing the concept of a "closed set" in your BFS? The standard way of doing that is to simply maintain a separate `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` of elements already encountered. That way, you get O(lg *n*) or O(1) lookup, while iterating through a queue, if it were supported, would take O(*n*) time.

Comment: Thanks. I think this works although I will have to empty the set at the beginning of each BFS round.

Comment: @Ari: what do you mean by a round?

Comment: I need to run BFS multiple times. By round I mean each iteration **i** that I am running the BFS algorithm. For each node I have a variable **c** that I increment upon visit. I only visit each node if  that node has not been visited in iteration i, i.e. c < i.

Comment: @Ari: Ok. Then just make BFS a function and make your closed set a local variable within the function. No need to explicitly clear it.

Comment: I ended up making the counter a member variable of each node. This saves me from searching in the closed/open set.

Answer (score -2):

the accepted answer is silly.

each of the items in a BFS search will go through three states: not-visited, visited-but-not-complete, visited.   For search purposes you can trim this down to visited or not-visited...

you simply need to use a flag...

the flag just alternates.

well, with the first traversal of the tree each node will start at false (not-visited) and go to true (visited).   At the second traversal it will switch to true (not-visited) and go to false (visited).

so all you have to do is to keep a separate flag that simply changes state on each traversal...

then your logic is

```
if ( visitedFlag ^ alternatingFlagStateOfTree )
{
    visitedFlag ^= 1;
}
```

basically the alternatingFlagStateOfTree is just used to indicate if a true is visited or a false is visited state.  Each run alternates so we just swap them around.

This entirely eliminates the need for the set(), all the memory overhead, etc. as well as eliminated any need to reset the flag values between runs.

This technique can be used for more complex states, so long as there is a consistent ending state across all items being traversed.   You simply do some math to reset what the flag value is to return the state back to base-state.

Comment: Please be nice to others asking or answering questions, even if you do not like them. You might want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/conduct. I would recommend removing the first sentence in your answer or at least phrasing it in a more constructive way (which part do you not agree with, ...).