# C++ Equiv. of C#'s intQueue.Contains()

Tags: c#, c++, queue, translate, fifo

I'm translating a good bit of code from C# to C++ and I'm stuck on a seemingly basic question.

I want to do a simple evaluation to see if a FIFO queue of int's contains a particular int.  This cannot be hard to do, but I can't seem to find a good example on Google.

```
if(intQueue.Contains(value)){ /* do some stuff */ }
```

I found this same question asked over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550962/find-if-an-item-already-exists-in-stl-queue), but the answer does not really apply to my situation.  Please help! Thanks!

Comment: `intQueue` is a variable not a type. Probably type is `Queue<int>`? I would use a `deque` in c++ and the `find` member function.

Comment: Right.  intQueue is a variable name used here as an example.  Perhaps a deque is better suited to this case.  Thank you for your comment.  I'll look into that.

Comment: Correction. I meant `std::find`. deque has no find member function.

Comment: Would `list<>` suffice?

Comment: I don't believe so in this case.  The main use is as a queue.  I do need that functionality for my program.

Comment: An STL queue is an adapter for an underlying container- usually a deque or list. Both of which directly support their use as a queue. A bonus-you can use std::find on them.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use `std::find()` located in `<algorithm>`. You need to pass it the beginning and end iterators, which can't be accessed using the `queue` class, so a good alternative would be `deque`.

A deque functions similarly to a queue in that items can be pushed and popped off it, but items are not restricted to the "first in first out" model. Items can be popped and pushed both from the back and the front. This is how the `queue` class stores its elements internally by default.

```
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // initialize deque with ints 3, 2, 1
    std::deque<int> intDeque{ 3, 2, 1 };

    auto it = std::find(intDeque.begin(), intDeque.end(), 2); // find 2 in intDeque

    if (it == intDeque.end()) {
        std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Found!" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The above uses c++11, if you don't have access to that, you can do the same like this:

```
std::deque<int> intDeque;
// push elements onto the deque
intDeque.push_back(3);
intDeque.push_back(2);
intDeque.push_back(1);

std::deque<int>::iterator it = std::find(intDeque.begin(), intDeque.end(), 2); // find 2 in intDeque
```

Answer (score 0):

'PC Luddite' has the answer, but here it is in the direct conversion of your example:

```
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>

...

std::deque<int> intQueue;
if (std::find(intQueue.begin(), intQueue.end(), value) != intQueue.end())
{
}
```

Comment: You can't do this with `queue`. `queue` doesn't give you access to beginning and end iterators.

Answer (score 0):

So, if using a `deque` or `list` directly is not acceptable and `queue` does not lend itself to searching efficiently.  Let's extend queue with cbegin/cend and enable `std::find`.

```
template <typename _Ty, typename _Container = deque<_Ty>>
class searchable_queue : public std::queue<_Ty, _Container>
{
public:
    template<class... _Axx>
    searchable_queue(_Axx&&... _Ax) 
        : std::queue<_Ty, _Container>(std::forward<_Axx>(_Ax)...)
    {}

    typename _Container::const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept
    { 
         return (c.cbegin());
    }

    typename _Container::const_iterator cend() const noexcept
    {   
        return (c.cend());
    }
};

int main() 
{
    list<int> l = { 11, 22, 44, 55 };
    auto q = searchable_queue<int,list<int>>(std::move(l));
    auto res = std::find(q.cbegin(), q.cend(), 22);
    cout << boolalpha << (res != q.cend()) << '\n'; //displays 'true'
    res = std::find(q.cbegin(), q.cend(), 77);
    cout << boolalpha << (res != q.cend()) << '\n'; // displays 'false'
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use C++ 11 and upwards, I'd suggest using [`any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) algorithm:

```
#include <algorithm>

if(std::any_of(intQueue.begin(), intQueue.end(), value))
{
  //do some stuff here
}
```

Does not matter what data structure one might use, as long as it offers iterators.

**Note!** The only thing you need to pay attention to is the desired complexity. Here you might end up with the *O(N)* comparisons. **However**, if the underlying **queue is** known to be **sorted** (e.g. *priority queue*), you can improve the runtime to be *O(log N)*. The only problem is that (e.g. [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)) does not offer you iterators and you will either need another `std::priority_queue` instance to put elements to after you pop the head or you sort your data-structure in-place and use the [`std::binary_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) to check if the desired element is there:

```
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>

// std::deque<int> intQueue;
std::sort(intQueue.begin(), intQueue.end()); // !!! this is O(N log N) !!!


if(std::binary_search(intQueue.begin(), intQueue.end(), value)) // O(log N)
{
  //do some stuff here
}
```

**As it turns out:** You need to maintain the sorted condition after initial sorting  (with *O(log N)* insertion time), otherwise you will end up with worse runtime complexity. Especially, you might need the elements as states in FIFO order, than the second approach is not applicable.